# How can I avoid indent for continue curly bracket after reformatting code in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

This is what I want

[image]

But I actually get this after reformat the code.
[image]

The reason I want to have that is because without new line it looks like this:
[image]

Not very tidy...

Comment: Why are you putting a new line after the flow's `}`?

Comment: Take a look 3rd screenshot I just uploaded..that is the reason. I want to `flowOn`, `delayFlow`, `collect` all align to the same vertical line. That looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but I can point you in to that direction.

Follow the direction below:

In Android Studio Go to,

1. **File** -> **Settings** *(Ctrl+Alt+S in windows)*
2. Expand the **Editor** option-> Expand **Code Style** option -> Select **Kotlin**
3. Select '**Wrapping and Braces**' from Tab window there on right pane
4. Find '**Chained Function calls**' there & adjust accordingly

---

I would suggest following settings:

Select **Wrap always** for *Chained Function calls* & Check **Use continuation indent**, Uncheck **Wrap first call** if checked previously.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you try this by yourself?? It is worse..https://imgur.com/MfZb752  https://imgur.com/NpFIkgq